# Android CMake. How to compile single .h and .hpp when make .so?

Tags: android, c++, cmake, java-native-interface

I am trying to build .so library for my android app using CMake in Android Studio. CMakeLists.txt file looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

file(GLOB CORE_SOURCES "src/main/cpp/ine/Core/*.cpp")
file(GLOB CORE_HEADERS "src/main/cpp/ine/Core/*.hpp")
file(GLOB LA256_SOURCES "src/main/cpp/ine/Geometry/*.cpp")
file(GLOB LA256_HEADERS "src/main/cpp/ine/Geometry/*.hpp")
file(GLOB PLATFORMS_SOURCES "src/main/cpp/ine/Platforms/*.cpp")
file(GLOB PLATFORMS_HEADERS "src/main/cpp/ine/Platforms/*.hpp")


add_library( naive-lib
             SHARED

             src/main/cpp/GEngine/Platforms/com_giena_apptest_ine.h
             ${CORE_SOURCES}
             ${CORE_HEADERS}
             ${GEOMETRY_SOURCES}
             ${GEOMETRY_HEADERS}
             ${PLATFORMS_SOURCES}
             ${PLATFORMS_HEADERS}
             )

find_library( 
              log-lib
              log )


target_link_libraries( native-lib
                       android
                       EGL
                       GLESv2
                       ${log-lib} )
```

.cpp , .c with .hpp and .h files are assembling good, but single .hpp and .h (without .cpp and .c acordingly) are not.

So, how can I include single single .hpp and .h files to the .so?

Comment: Those are header files, you are not supposed to compile them.

Comment: hm...So what about c++ templates that is .hpp?

Comment: Templates that are in header files will be inlined into code that is using them. It is actually possible to compile certain instantiations of those templates into shared library but that would require some additional work and most likely it is not required in your case.

Comment: Well, thank you, I understand. But what do I need to do in the case when I generated jni-functions via javah util for my java class. This is a .h file. Do I need to write a .c file for it?

Comment: Question close. Thank you.